# Understanding Google Ads ,GA4 in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, analytics, google-ads-api

I have data from google analytics and google ads into google bigQuery .i want to query data from table inside google analytics data set and google ads datasets but i could not figure out a key or value on which  i could combine both datasets

I have tried a lot of solution available online .Important thing is that **gclid** is coming null in google Analytics .

- i have linked both accounts (GA4 And Google Ads)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.